# How to get the original value(when package1 called first time) of a variable from package1 to another package3

Tags: java, variables, jobs

I have created a `package1` with a variable `startTime` and some other code. I have directly called a method (`firstProgram`) of this package from `JobScheduler` at the beginning of Project execution. Now I want this same value to `package3` at the end of Project, but I'm getting null value.

P1.java

```java
package com.package1;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ClassP1 {
    private String startTime;

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public void startTime() {
        DateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy HH:mm:ss");
        setStartTime(dF.format(new Date()));
        System.out.println("Desired Start Time: " + getStartTime());
    }
}
```

There are many other packages called in between.

P3.java

```java
package com.package3;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.package1.ClassP1;

public class ClassP3 {
    private String endTime;

    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public void program() {
        ClassP1 p1 = new ClassP1();
        System.out.println("Start Time: " + p1.getStartTime()); // I want this Start Time when exact job start
        DateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy HH:mm:ss");
        setEndTime(dF.format(new Date()));
        System.out.println("End Time: " + getEndTime());
    }
}
```

MainPackage.java

```java
package mainpackage;

import com.package3.*;
import com.package1.*;

public class MainPackage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassP1 p1 = new ClassP1();
        p1.startTime();

        ClassP3 p3 = new ClassP3();
        p3.program();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Desired Start Time: 11-05-2023 00:14:00
Start Time: null
End Time: 11-05-2023 00:14:01
```

Basically I want Job start time and Job End Time but I'm getting:

```
Job Start Time as **null**
```

How to get Job start time from call of very first method?

Comment: The question is missing some code that’s needed to answer. What calls `firstProgram`, `setStartTime`, and `sendStatusMail`?

Comment: Since you haven't responded with details, I voted to close. Here are a few misconceptions to clear up: Variables and methods don't belong directly to packages, they belong to classes, and classes belong to packages. The fact that these classes are in different packages has no bearing on this specific problem. One of these must be true: 1) `setStartTime` was never called on the instance of `EndClass` that `sendStatusMail` was called on, or 2) it was called with an instance of `StartClass` that has not had its `firstProgram` method called, or 3) missing code sets one of the variables to null.

Comment: Hi @TimMoore This code link Please read in Readme.md 
 https://github.com/lokeshparihar100/VariablePass

Comment: It does not call startTime on p1 here https://github.com/lokeshparihar100/VariablePass/blob/fe5eab32ae926eb516c0b6e15fb14973ad0f5729/VariablePass/src/com/package3/ClassP3.java#L22

Comment: Your program is creating two different instances of `ClassComP1` and only calls startTime on one of them.

Comment: In method `program`, of class `ClassP3`, you create a new `ClassP1` instance. This instance has nothing to do with the instance that you created in method `main` of class `MainPackage`. Hence variable `startTime`, of `ClassP1` instance that you created in method `program`, is null. There are several ways to solve the problem. One way is to call method `startTime` on the `ClassP1` instance that you create in method `program`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Static** keyword has resolved my issue.
In package1 (P1.java) change as below:

```
private static startTime;
```

Static keyword will store the value in 1st call and save it for next use.